# Would Attacking An ISIS Website Be Illegal

Tags: legal

I made a DDoS script that floods an ISIS websites with post requests, if enough people use the script, it could take down the website.

(Presuming it works) Would that be illegal and would I be arrested. The reason I ask is that it's a terrorist group that the U.S. and many other countries want them gone, so would it be legal, illegal? If it is illegal, is there anyway I could do it legally?

Comment: We are not a law community and we won't give advice on attacking any systems.

Comment: Still illegal. It's called "vigilantism".

Comment: If you can verify that only ISIS uses the server, it may be the right thing to do depending on your ethics.  But it is still illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are not really law expert (see law.stackexchange.com), but consider this: justice does not usually consider who owns the website you'd be DDoS-ing.

Furthermore, you have no idea if the site you are flooding is a mutualised server, where your attack could also affect other person's websites.

So on a general rule, if DDoS is illegal, DDoS ISIS websites remains illegal.